# данные из активити в Button navigation

Tags: android, bottom-navigation-view

у меня есть панель button navigation с 5 кнопками снизу и несколько активити. Пользователь на второй кнопке начинает заполнять данные, там он вписывает в 4 активностях данные. На последней активности отображается его номер и фио,после чего снизу есть кнопка перехода на главную страницу ( это первая из 5 кнопок), как мне сделать чтобы при нажатии на эту кнопку пользователь оказался на главной странице и потом,при его желании он мог нажать на 5 кнопку где бы появились эти данные. То есть он переходит с 4 активности где все данные на главный экран и потом переходит на 5 кнопку и экраном, где все данные. Как это можно сделать? желательно для переноса использовать intent, его я уже хорошо изучил...

Comment: Не очень понятно что и как вы делаете и что хотите сделать. Однако, кажется, вы неправильно используете bOttomNavigationView. Оно должно переключать фрагменты, а не активити. Также вам, возможно, стоит хранить данные в БД или, хотя бы, в SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите всерьез заняться мобильной разработкой, то всё это не подойдет, нужно делать иначе.
Активити должна быть одна, в ней только меню и пустой контейнер (FrameLayout), в котором будут запускаться фрагменты, содержащие экраны приложения.
Как это правильно сделать, хорошо описано здесь:
https://coderlessons.com/articles/mobilnaia-razrabotka-articles/kak-kodirovat-nizhniuiu-panel-navigatsii-dlia-prilozheniia-dlia-android

Что касается передачи данных, интенты как раз не желательны.
Ключевое слово для вас: viewmodel, изучите эту тему обязательно, без нее нет современной мобильной разработки.
Вам нужно завести одну общую для всех фрагментов вьюмодель, в которой будут храниться данные и доступ к которой будет с любого экрана.